# Form a json by traversing folders in the local system

Tags: java, json

I have a requirement like I need to form a josn through java by traversing the folders in local system to display in the tree structure.(Maybe chances of any number of folders, subfolder and files in it )

I have written the code like

```
 import java.io.File;
 public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File inputFolder = new File("D:\\gaja\\jQuery\\test");
        traverse(inputFolder, "");
    }
    public static void traverse(File parentNode, String leftIndent) {
        if (parentNode.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println(leftIndent + parentNode.getName());
            // Use left padding to create tree structure in the console output.
            leftIndent += "   ";
 File childNodes[] = parentNode.listFiles();
            for (File childNode : childNodes) {
                traverse(childNode, leftIndent);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(leftIndent + parentNode.getName());
        }
    }
 }
```

It is traversing the folders successfully and giving the output as follows:

```
           test
              test1
                 resume.txt
                 test1.1
                   test1.1.1
                 test1.2
             test2
                test2.1
                   r.txt
                test2.2
            test3
               hdhf.odt
```

but I am unable to form the json accordingly..

I want the josn like this

```
             [{ "folders": [
                    { "name": "Folder 1", "files": [{ "name": "File 1.jpg" 
       }, { "name": "File 2.png" }], "folders": [
                        { "name": "Subfolder 1", "files": [{ "name": 
               "Subfile 1.txt" }] },
                        { "name": "Subfolder 2" }
                    ]}

                ]},{ "folders": [
                    { "name": "Folder 1", "files": [{ "name": "File 1.jpg" }, { "name": "File 2.png" }], "folders": [
                        { "name": "Subfolder 1", "files": [{ "name": "Subfile 1.txt" }] },
                        { "name": "Subfolder 2" }
                    ]}

                ]},{ "folders": [
                    { "name": "Folder 1", "files": [{ "name": "File 1.jpg" }, { "name": "File 2.png" }], "folders": [
                        { "name": "Subfolder 1", "files": [{ "name": "Subfile 1.txt" }] },
                        { "name": "Subfolder 2" }
                    ]}

                ]},{ "folders": [
                    { "name": "Folder 1", "files": [{ "name": "File 1.jpg" }, { "name": "File 2.png" }], "folders": [
                        { "name": "Subfolder 1", "files": [{ "name": "Subfile 1.txt" }] },
                        { "name": "Subfolder 2" }
                    ]}

                ]}]
```

I hope I will get the solution for this. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please see: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch , http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt, [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's about the same thing:

```
private static void traverse(File parentNode, String leftIndent) {
    System.out.println(leftIndent + "{");
    String indent = leftIndent + "    ";
    System.out.print(indent + "\"name\":\""
            + parentNode.getName() + "\"");
    if (!parentNode.isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println();
    } else {
        array(parentNode.listFiles(file -> file.isFile()), "files", indent);
        array(parentNode.listFiles(file -> file.isDirectory()), "folders", indent);
    }
    System.out.print(leftIndent + "}");
}

private static void array(File[] files, String attr, String leftIndent) {
    if (files == null || files.length == 0) {
        System.out.println();
    } else {
        System.out.println(",");
        System.out.print(leftIndent + "\"" + attr + "\":[");
        String indent = leftIndent + "    ";
        boolean first = true;
        for (File file: files)  {
            if (first) {
                System.out.println();
                first = false;
            } else {
                System.out.println(",");
            }
            traverse(file, indent);
        }
        System.out.print("]");
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

Now let's put that in a servlet:

```
public class DirectoryServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final File BASE_DIR = new File("D://");

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String path = request.getParameter("path");
        File file;
        if (path == null || path.isEmpty()) {
            file = BASE_DIR;
        } else {
            file = new File(BASE_DIR, path);
        }
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            traverse(out, file, "");
        }
    }

    private static void traverse(PrintWriter out, File parentNode,
            String leftIndent) {
        out.println(leftIndent + "{");
        String indent = leftIndent + "    ";
        out.print(indent + "\"name\":\""
                + parentNode.getName() + "\"");
        if (!parentNode.isDirectory()) {
            out.println();
        } else {
            array(out, parentNode.listFiles(file -> file.isFile()), "files", indent);
            array(out, parentNode.listFiles(file -> file.isDirectory()), "folders", indent);
        }
        out.print(leftIndent + "}");
    }

    private static void array(PrintWriter out, File[] files, String attr,
            String leftIndent) {
        if (files == null || files.length == 0) {
            out.println();
        } else {
            out.println(",");
            out.print(leftIndent + "\"" + attr + "\":[");
            String indent = leftIndent + "    ";
            boolean first = true;
            for (File file: files)  {
                if (first) {
                    out.println();
                    first = false;
                } else {
                    out.println(",");
                }
                traverse(out, file, indent);
            }
            out.print("]");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "JSON directory structure";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Maurice, thanks a lot. It is printing exactly what I am trying to do. I need the json object to return it to js (java to js) so that I can form the ui. while I am trying to form the json I am getting different format .can you please help me with this. ??

Comment: @MounikaGaja I don't get what You're trying to do. What do you mean by "return it to js"? do you have a Java server and you're querying it Ajax-style?

Comment: yes Maurice I am doing it Ajax style.. instead of printing in sysouts i want to form a whole json in java code and send it as a response to ajax call.

Comment: @MounikaGaja are You using a servlet engine such as tomcat?

Comment: @MounikaGaja OK, putting this in a servlet is pretty straightforward: see my update

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code to return the elements rather than printing the data. Here's an example based on your current code and using a new class called `MyFile` to store the data from the files:

```
public class MyFile {
    private String name;
    private List<MyFile> contents;
    //constructor, getters and setters, other methods...
}

public class Sample {
    public static MyFile traverse(File file) {
        if (!file.exists()) return null;
        MyFile myFile = new MyFile(file.getName());
        if (parentNode.isDirectory()) {
            File childNodes[] = parentNode.listFiles();
            List<MyFile> contents = new ArrayList<>();
            for (File childNode : childNodes) {
                contents.add(traverse(childNode));
            }
        }
        return myFile;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options to convert your string to JSON representation.

Step 1: Include JACKSON dependency in your project. There are several jars in JACKSON library.
Step 2: Create POJO's. These object will be converted to and from JSON. ...
Step 3: Convert Java Object to JSON and write JSON to a file. Convert CarFleet object into JSON and write that JSON to a file.

I would suggest you to create a object called Folders

```
class Folders {
    List<Folders> folderList;
    List<File> files;
    String folderName;
}
class File{
    String fileName;
}
```

By creating above structure and following http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/ you can easily convert to JSON object.